# ExtJS Page redirection

Tags: java, javascript, html, iframe, extjs4

This was something which was cracking my head for sometime.

1. I have a Web Page written in ExtJS+Java EE (Page A). I want to create a
   new browser tab on Button click and show page B.
2. B does some operation and does a complete form submit.
3. The result of this form submit has to be displayed in A (Which is open all the while).

For Example:

1. In Page A, I search for the tests available in the my learning management system and display it in a grid.
2. When the user clicks on a test, a new window opens with the test's url (Page B).
3. Once the user completes the test he clicks the submit in B.
4. The results of the test is shown on the grid in Page A.

The big problem is that I done have much control over the Page B or its source.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would need to do a window.open('Whatever Page B's url is'); when you click on the correct link per row in the grid.

From Page B, you could use window.opener to reference Page A.  So you can either refresh Page A by doing something like:

```
window.opener.location.reload();
```

or you could call whatever refresh type method that you define in Page A  from Page B eg.   window.opener.customMethod()